# elisp easy-menu positioning

Tags: emacs, elisp

This is to position the emacs user defined menu at a certain place in the menu bar.

Here are the different options I have used. None optimal

**[From First Principles]**

```
;; Define a top level Menue item "Openflow" and position it after "Tools"

(define-key-after global-map [menu-bar openflow] 
  (cons "Openflow" (make-sparse-keymap "Openflow")) 'Tools)

;; CAUTION: Menus are defined in reverse order. END comes first!!

(define-key global-map [menu-bar openflow openflow-download-mp]   
  '("download openflow mp image to target" . openflow-download-mp-image-to-target))

(define-key global-map [menu-bar openflow telnet-to-target] 
  '("Telnet to target" . (lambda () (interactive) (telnet target))))


(define-key global-map [menu-bar openflow separator4] '("---"))
;; Reading Upwards: All debugging  etc starts here

;; But here we need to add the new subheading first
(define-key global-map [menu-bar openflow cleanups] (cons "Cleanups" (make-sparse-keymap "Cleanups")))

(define-key global-map [menu-bar openflow cleanups lp-emake-clean] 
  '("LP emake_wrapper clean" . (lambda () (interactive) 
                        (openflow-emake-wrapper  my-openflow-lp-build-path "clean"))))


;; etc etc etc...
```

**[Weaknesses]**

Very Messy.. very confusing esp. the reverse order + submenu defs are in forward order :-)

**Easy Mode too automatic**

If I do the same thing in easy mode ..

```
(easy-menu-define openflow2 global-map "Openflow2"
  '("Openflow2"
    ["download openflow mp image to target" openflow-download-mp-image-to-target t]
    ["Telnet to target" (telnet target)]
    "-----"
    ("Cleanups"
     ["LP emake_wrapper clean" (openflow-emake-wrapper  my-openflow-lp-build-path "clean")] )))
```

**[Weaknesses]**

Very intuitive, very automatic, eliminates lamda functions etc etc etc.

***However, it adds in the first position before the "File" -- looks bad. There is no way to "define-key-after"***

**[Hybrid Model]**

The "hybrid model" (define-key-after sparse-keymap and easy-menu-add-item) is complicated but messy

```
(define-key-after global-map [menu-bar openflow3]
  (cons "Openflow3" (make-sparse-keymap "Openflow3")) 'Tools)

(easy-menu-add-item nil '("Openflow3") 
       ["download openflow mp image to target" openflow-download-mp-image-to-target])

(easy-menu-add-item nil '("Openflow3") 
    ["Telnet to target" (telnet target)])

(easy-menu-add-item nil '("Openflow3") 
    "-----")

(define-key-after global-map [menu-bar openflow3 cleanups3] 
  (cons "Cleanups3" (make-sparse-keymap "Cleanups3")) '("-----"))


(easy-menu-add-item nil '("Cleanups3") 
     ["LP emake_wrapper clean" (openflow-emake-wrapper  my-openflow-lp-build-path "clean")])
```

Here I cannot do nested menus

**Please please tell the newbie what I am doing wrong?**

Comment: I initially played around with it too when I first started using Emacs a year ago.  I eventually gave up and settled for the first slot to the far left, or an existing slot.  Now, I simply use a mouse pop-up menu that offers everything normally found in the menu-bar (plus some extra stuff that I have customized) and I hide the menu-bar completely.

Comment: You might want to check out a menubar library written by Drew Adams:  http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MenuBarPlus  There is a note on the internet indicating an opinion that the library offers more customizable options and better control -- that other person had the same problem as us -- i.e., trying to control the location with easy-menu:  http://emacs-fu.blogspot.com/2009/04/adding-custom-menus.html

Comment: Thank You. I am also giving up and going to use "first principles". The macro is nice and is too too automatic. Leave a note to look into it later!

Comment: Thank You. I am also giving up and going to use "first principles". The macro is nice and is too too automatic. Leave a note to look into it later!

Drew Adams also ends up positioning on the left and does not give me the flexibility I need.

I am handling mouse-3 for buffer related stuff like: compile, checkout, cscope functions, highlight-regexp, list-matching-lines, close, save etc.

All the elisp functions I wrote went to the menue and that is huge!

Comment: I don't understand your comment about me ending up by "*positioning on the left*". Positioning what? You can position menu-bar menus in *any order you want*. The order I use in [`menu-bar+.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/menu-bar%2b.el) reflects the vanilla order for the most part - not by accident, but because that is the order expect: `File`, `Edit`, etc. You are writing a lot in comments here, but you are not making it very clear what you want or what the problems are. ;-) As far as I can see, your question has been answered. But perhaps it is becoming a moving target...

Comment: "positioning on the left": If you use easy-menu in the format given (plz see my code above), it ends up placing the left side.
My questions are answered. yes!

Answer (score 2):

I'm using something like this:

```
(easy-menu-define openflow2 nil "Openflow2"
  '("Openflow2"
    ["download openflow mp image to target" openflow-download-mp-image-to-target t]
    ["Telnet to target" (telnet target)]
    "-----"
    ("Cleanups"
     ["LP emake_wrapper clean" (openflow-emake-wrapper  my-openflow-lp-build-path "clean")]
(define-key-after (lookup-key global-map [menu-bar])
  [openflow]
  (cons "Openflow" openflow2) 'tools)
```

to define a menu with easy-menu-define but put it at the correct place in the menu bar.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by a "nested menu"? If you mean a *submenu* then the answer is to do the same thing you did for the top-level menu: use `define-key` to bind a key to a *cons* whose *car* is the submenu name and whose *cdr* is a menu keymap.

Here is an example from [`dired+.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/dired%2b.el). It defines a submenu of the Dired menu-bar menu `Mark`, which is on variable `diredp-menu-bar-mark-menu`.

The menu keymap for the submenu is the value of variable `diredp-mark-tags-menu`, just as the menu keymap for its parent menu (the menu-bar menu) is the value of variable `diredp-menu-bar-mark-menu`.

```
;; Menu-bar `Mark' Menu.
(defvar diredp-menu-bar-mark-menu (make-sparse-keymap "Mark"))
(define-key dired-mode-map [menu-bar mark] (cons "Mark" diredp-menu-bar-mark-menu))


;; `Mark' > `Tagged' submenu.
(defvar diredp-mark-tags-menu (make-sparse-keymap "Tagged")
  "`Tags' submenu for Dired menu-bar `Mark' menu.")
(define-key diredp-menu-bar-mark-menu [mark-tags] (cons "Tagged" diredp-mark-tags-menu))

(define-key diredp-mark-tags-menu [diredp-unmark-files-tagged-none]
  '(menu-item "Unmark Not Tagged with Any..." diredp-unmark-files-tagged-none
    :help "Unmark files that are not tagged with *any* of the tags you enter"))
```

Consult the Elisp manual, node [`Defining Menus`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Defining-Menus.html#Defining-Menus), for more info.

---

If you really want to use easy-menu to define your submenu (as you say in your comment, below), take a look at library [`facemenu+.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/facemenu%2b.el). It does that (for a popup menu, not a menu-bar menu, but the idea is the same).

For example:

```
(easy-menu-add-item 
 facemenu-menu
 () (easy-menu-create-menu              ; (menu-name menu-items)
     "Syntax Highlighting (Font Lock)"
     '(["In All Buffers" global-font-lock-mode
        :style toggle :selected global-font-lock-mode
        :active t]
       ["In Current Buffer" font-lock-mode
        :style toggle :selected font-lock-mode :active t]
       "--"
       ["More In Current Buffer" font-lock-fontify-more
        (nth 2 (if (boundp 'flm-font-lock-fontify-level)
                   flm-font-lock-fontify-level
                 font-lock-fontify-level))]
       ["Less In Current Buffer" font-lock-fontify-less
        (nth 1 (if (boundp 'flm-font-lock-fontify-level)
                   flm-font-lock-fontify-level
                 font-lock-fontify-level))]
       "--"
       ["Cycle Keywords (Icicles)"
        icicle-next-font-lock-keywords-repeat
        :active
        (and (boundp 'icicle-mode)  icicle-mode
         (fboundp 'icicle-next-font-lock-keywords-repeat))]
       ["+ Choose Keywords (Icicles)" icicle-font-lock-keyword
        :active (and (boundp 'icicle-mode)  icicle-mode
                 (fboundp 'icicle-font-lock-keyword))]))
 "Syntax Highlighting (Font Lock)")
```

---

As for relative positioning of a submenu in an existing menu, use `define-key-after` (as usual).

Comment: Hi:  That is from first principles. I can do everything from first principles except that uses up lot of space in init.el. And reads clunky. Not so clean as easy-menu

Comment: Clunkiness is in the eye of the beholder. ;-) I agree with you that easy-menu is simpler (if perhaps less lispier) at first sight. I use both.  But I end up using the "first principles" approach when I need clarity and flexibility. Oh, and if you are putting stuff like this in your init file then you are making a mistake (IMHO). Put such code in a separate file, which you load from your init file (which is preferably itself the value of option `custom-file`).

Comment: Thank You! I guess I am going to stick to the "first principles" approach of manually defining an keymap and adding keys.

Comment: If you do not mind, if you use easy-menu then is to add items on an existing top-level menu or you happy with the leftmost position?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question. Could you please rephrase it? But did you see the update I made to the answer, to show you how to use easy-menu to add a submenu?

Comment: Here are the Qs (assuming you do not mind): (a)when do u use easy-menu? (b) Do you use it for adding the top menu? (c) When do u use "define-key"?

This will give me some inputs for a newbie.

Comment: I don't really have an answer to those questions. I generally don't bother with easy-menu. But I don't have a particular reason for that.

Comment: @Drew You said "I use both." followed by "I generally don't bother with easy-menu." - that seems contradictory. Also, your examples don't show to add a menu in a particular position of an existing menu after the fact, a key point of the original question I think.

Comment: @NetMage: (1) I do use both. I don't use easy-menu very much. No contradiction. I use it, for example, when the menu that I'm modifying was created using easy-menu (e.g. by some other library). (2) I've added a mention of `define-key-after`. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do something like define-key-after with Easy Menu - but it is before. I added this to my .emacs.el:

```
;***
;*** Edit Menu additions

(easy-menu-define edit-occur-menu nil "Edit Occur menu"
  '("Occur"
    ["Occur..." occur]
    ["Flush Matching Lines..." flush-lines]
    ["Keep Matching Lines..." keep-lines]
    "---"
    ["How Many..." how-many]
    ))
(easy-menu-add-item nil '("Edit") edit-occur-menu "Go To")
```

The last line adds the new `edit-occur-menu` to the global menu bar in the `Edit` menu before the `Go To` menu item.